# How to switch to a newly opened tab by clicking a link in a pop up window using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, tabs, popup

I am playing with Firefox tabs and windows in Selenium.

My code opens a page in Firefox window. Then it clicks a link that causes a pop up window to show up. After that this:

```
for wh in driver.window_handles:
    print(wh)
```

... gives this output:

```
2147483649
2147483704
```

..., where `2147483649` corresponds to the opened at the beginning page, and `2147483704` to the pop up window.

Then the code clicks a link in this pop up window, which causes a new tab to open in the window with the opened at the beginning page. Then this:

```
for wh in driver.window_handles:
    print(wh)
```

... gives this output:

```
2147483649
2147483704
```

... again, even though a new tab was opened. Note that the newly opened tab is not there.

Then the code closes the window:

```
driver.close()
```

Then this:

```
for wh in driver.window_handles:
    print(wh)
```

... gives this output:

```
2147483649
2147483707
```

..., where `2147483649` corresponds to the opened at the beginning page, and `2147483707` to the tab that was opened by clicking a link in the pop up window (I've checked it).

Such behavior was unexpected for me.

Now, the main question is, how to switch to the tab, which was opened by clicking a link in the pop up window, without closing the pop up window?

Comment: To help you out more please post the relevant html code in text format and your code snippet for switch action.

Comment: Sorry, @theGuy, I can't do that. I would have to write such pages from scratch. Maybe I'll do this later, but I think that I described the problem clearly.

Comment: My guess is that it's a timing issue. The first window pops up quickly so is printed in the list where the second window is slower and so the printed list doesn't include it. You can add a custom wait that will wait until the window handle count increases and that should solve this issue.